# What are the pros and cons of a language using whitespace vs. {}'s to indicate scope?

Tags: coding-style

There seems to be a conflict over whether its better to use whitespace or tokens like brackets to indicate scope. I've seen many praise python's solution to the inconsistent indentation problem, [but many disagree:](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/which-programming-language-do-you-really-hate/3836#3836)

> Any language that has whitespace as tokens needs to die.

posted later on the same answer:

> I was sortof anti-whitespace-as-tokens, until I actually tried it. It probably helped that my personal white-space layout pretty much matches what everyone in python-land uses. Perhaps it's that I am a bit minimalist, but if you're going to indent anyways, why bother with the {}s?

I can see some clear arguments for each side:

using whitespace:

- helps reduce inconsistent indentation in code
- clears the screen by replace visible tokens with whitespace to serve the same purpose

using tokens:

- much easier to cut and paste code to different levels (you don't have to fix the
  indentation)
- more consistent. Some text editors display whitespace differently.
- more popular currently.

Are there any points I missed? Which do you prefer? Any words of wisdom after having worked with one or the other for a long time?

---

PS. I hate it when languages don't use the same token for each control structure. VB is really annoying with its `End If` and `End While` statements, most other languages just use {}'s for everything. But maybe that's a topic for a different question...

Comment: I wouln't say it's "much easier to cut and paste". It's only little easier.

Comment: As long as you keep blocks of code small and organized, the tokens really shouldn't matter... by the way, love the 'holy-war' tag, lol

Comment: "Some text editors display whitespace differently.": ?? "more popular currently.": Popularity is often not related to the quality of an idea.

Comment: I love whitespace syntax, and I loved coding in CoffeeScript and Haskell (yeah I know its hard).  I've coded a bunch in JavaScript and C, and I just can't go back to }.  However, Lisp s-expressions when they are replaced with box divs is best though : )

Comment: I think it makes it harder to spot errors if you have to rely on whitespace alone.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205836/generating-random-sequences-of-dna

The only difference between the OP's code and the answer is the extra space.
 Having a } to delimit which code is inside the for loop and which is not is a lot clearer.

Answer (score 15):

I think a lot of us programmers (myself included) have a tendency to "logicalize" every decision.  That's fine, but not every question has a logical answer.  For instance, I doubt that chefs post questions on chefoverflow (if such a thing exists) asking for the pros and cons of apple pie vs cherry pie.  It's a question of which you like better.

With that in mind, I think the simplest answer is to say "Some people like braces, some people like whitespace" and leave it at that.

Comment: Incidentally: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, something that's a pro for some could be a con for others.

Comment: Excellent point. Personally I think they work together, and as long as the sope is clear, I won't complain (much).

Comment: I don’t agree with your analogy. There are pretty objective reasons to believe that whitespace-dependent syntax hampers programmer productivity, even in the programmers who love it. It’s a bit like saying people just don’t like the taste of cyanide — everyone’s just “logicalising” when they say that it’s poisonous. No. It doesn’t matter how much you love it, it’s still gonna kill you.

Comment: P.S. The word you’re actually looking for is [rationalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalization_%28making_excuses%29). Also, *everyone* has a tendency to rationalise, not just programmers.

Comment: JasonBaker -- you are referring to one, common use of the word "rationalize", but it is by no means the only one. @Timwi is using the word in its more general (and original) meaning.

Comment: People spend more time reading code than writing it, and sure you might have to do some Shift+TABs when copy/pasting or remember the key to turn spaces to tabs, but the benefits to readability save time IMO.

Answer (score 13):

At the risk of sounding like an utter fanboy, I think everyone who claims that whitespace “helps reduce inconsistent indentation in code” has never used Visual Studio. With a single command (I think the default shortcut is Ctrl+K,D), all the indentation is instantaneously consistent¹. Furthermore, when pasting code the indentation is instantaneously corrected without having to do anything at all, and the same is true when writing new code or when wrapping something in an `if` or some other block (reformat happens as the `}` is typed). Furthermore, pressing Enter after a completed statement always places the cursor at the correct indentation level for the next statement, even if the previous statement was indented further because of an `if` or similar, making it very difficult to accidentally think that a statement is still under an `if` when it isn’t.

**The point I’m trying to make is *not* that Visual Studio is great.** The point I’m trying to make is that the IDE can automate indentation-fixing (and other formatting issues), but *only if the meaning of the program does not depend on its formatting.* This gives the programmer a greater opportunity to focus on the actual programming task. A syntax like Python’s is counterproductive: it is not possible to write an IDE that can “fix” the indentation of Python code because the indentation itself specifies some of the semantics.

---

¹ <sub>*(I know there is a special case which VS refuses to reformat, namely array literals that span multiple lines, but that’s beside the point.)*</sub>

Comment: Great point. I use ReSharper, which fixes the indentation as soon as you type "}". You can configure it to "fix" your indentation in any way you like (e.g. K&R-style braces, different rules for anonymous classes, etc).

Comment: Python indentation does not need fixing because it does not get broken (without someone noticing!). It is impossible to write Purify (program that helps detect memory leaks) for C# either, does not mean C++ memory management is superior.

Comment: @Dean: Why do so many people think they need Resharper for everything? What you describe is already in Visual Studio without Resharper.

Comment: @dbkk: Your indentation is broken as soon as you add an `if` line anywhere. You then have to proceed to fix the indentation manually.

Comment: @Timwi Select lines. Tab. Done. You'd need to do just about the same amount of work to add the two brackets... and in addition fix the indentation too -- program compiles fine without it, but it's the right thing to do.

Comment: @Timwi: I dunno, ReSharper is the first thing I install on top of Visual Studio, so I don't actually know anymore what ReSharper provides and what's in the base package :-)

Comment: @dbkk: No, in VS you don’t need to fix the indentation. And you don’t even need to add any brackets if all you’re doing is pasting something. I suggest that you use it and try it before you comment on it.

Comment: you probably haven't worked on a team where indentation was lazy, inconsistent, etc. and fixing it was discouraged because it makes code diffs impossible.

Comment: @Kevin: Correct, I haven’t, and frankly, I wouldn’t want to. I’d insist on fixing all of it in one go, which causes only *one* unreadable diff which *only* affects insignificant whitespace and fixes all future diffs. Anything else would be counterproductive and harmful to the project.

Comment: @dbkk Python indentation can get broken.  I'm not exactly sure how it happened, but someone managed to check in an if statement that increased indenting by 3 spaces rather than the 4 specified by our code style guidelines.  Took a good 10 minutes to figure out what was going on, since 1 space was small enough to accidentally skim over (with blank lines at the top and bottom)...

Comment: @Timwi: It may be true that an IDE can't fix the indentation of Python code, just like it can't fix C code which has curlies in the wrong places. True, but not very meaningful. By definition, Python code has to always be indented correctly, or it won't work. Also, please note that Sublime Text can automatically shift the indentation of cut-and-pasted code to match its surroundings... which in practice is just as good as what you are describing.

Comment: Well I live the whitespace syntax cuz no more empty lines with }, which has nothing to do with the IDE;  and I have forgotten to delete the } more than once...  JavaScript is the worst with its closures where you have to write ugly });, and thats why I'm sad that CoffeeScript didn't catch on.  PureScript, Elm, Haskell, Idris, Agda -> white space sensitivity belongs to the future.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I find I need the blank line introduced by having a token on it's own line to make my mind realise that the code is in another scope.

I hate it when in python people go:

```
if something
    do something
    do somethingelse

    cleanup
else
    do the other thing
```

while in token land I hate when people copy and paste **and don't clean up the indentation**,

```
if something
{
I have been too lazy
      {
            to clean up
            }
what I pasted
}
```

or **don't use a separate line for the token**.

```
if something {
    I find this confusing
}
else {
especially when combined with the previous 
do something
}
```

I can read all three, but they aren't as I expect and I have to expend effort to parse them and as [Joel says](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html) when things don't work like you expect it makes you frustrated.

Answer (score 3):

Pro: There are no indentation/curly-brace-placement holy wars in the Python world as far as I know. Making this decision on behalf of developers has probably saved some pain.

Con: Anonymous functions are limited to one line. Sounds ok, but I frequently find myself writing up multi-line `lambda`s in Scheme (mostly to feed to `map` or `apply` in exactly one place, so it wouldn't make sense to declare separately).

Comment: Worth a read: [Everyone Indents Correctly All The Time In All Languages](http://slott-softwarearchitect.blogspot.com/2010/10/python-and-syntactic-whitespace-problem.html)

Comment: Multi line expressions are supported in Python -- just put \ at the end of a line.

Comment: To be fair, the lack of multiline lambdas is a limitation of Python, not of whitespace in general. In my whitespace-delimited language, if you introduce a lambda and an indented block follows, the block is used as the lambda body.

Comment: @Note - Ok, yes, fair. Python is just the only whitespace delimited language I have any experience with. @dbkk so you're saying that `lambda n: a = n \\na.sort() \\na[0:3]` **wouldn't** return a syntax error? The ` \ ` trick lets you spread your single-line lambda across multiple lines, but you still don't get more than one **actual** line.

Comment: Haskell, CoffeeScript use whitespace but don't have the single line lambda limitation.

Answer (score 3):

The problem I found with a whitespace language was with multi-page conditional expressions. Adding a line in the middle of page two, and getting off by one space in the middle of all mess, can drastically alter the logic of your code. And even if someone's code is "correct", trying to read it makes a terrible guessing game. Which "if" is this 'else' for? I can count braces much easier than I can count invisible blank characters. And the posting machinery on this site keeps smashing them into a single space.

```
IMHO "{{{{{" is more reliable than "     ".
```

Comment: If you use multi-page conditional expressions you have other problems. Just don’t do it. In fact, even with curly braces, the code becomes an unreadable mess. This is actually another benefit of whitespace indentation: it prevents you from writing such horrible code.

Comment: Seriously, a conditional multiple *pages* long?

Answer (score 3):

{} adds redundancy. Too much redundancy is bad, too few is bad. And manualy entering it is bad, esp. if its hard to use it.

So in times of bad/no IDE, whitespace style could be slightly better. But with powerfull IDE, braces are better.

Comment: You make a good point about redundancy I think. I've been mulling over parser-recovery for compilers for a while (following Clang's very interesting attempts to issue Fix-Its for the code) and what really helps here is that there is redundancy. Therefore, I think that no redundancy, while great in a perfect world, is actually harmful for real world programming. When normally redundant sources of information disagree, then it may be that a typo/mistake was made; without redundancy, this potential error goes undetected! *That being said, I prefer no braces ;)*

Comment: "Noise" was the word Erik Meijer used in his Haskell videos.

Comment: What if you delete a block and you forget to delete the } or delete the { by mistake when doing the opposite?  Redundancy goes against DRY IMO.

Comment: @aoeu256 I agree, redundancy does go against dry, but I think being dry is a balancing act. After all, unit tests effectively do the same thing. If your code is working, unit tests are a form of redundancy; they are wet. Perhaps it's better because unit tests aren't part of the functional code, more along the lines of documentation, but it does point out that certain forms of redundancy in certain situations are good. How much to include is a balancing act. It can catch mistakes or make code more clear, but it also can create rigidity and clutter up the code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's really a *versus*.
Pythoneers often criticize braces programmers as if they would readily violate indentation because they can.
In fact I always used 100% consistent indentation even before knowing about Python and its indentation scoping.

The fact is that braces languages could also impose correct indentation in the compiler and we would have the best of both worlds. See? no *versus* at all.

Pythoneers would argue that braces are useless when indentation is part of the syntax, but they are not, braces improve readability.  I tried programming Python and it's a very interesting language for me, but have you tried having `if-elif` chains of more than 2 or 3 indentation levels? they don't look so neat anymore.

PS: I wrote *braces* but in a more general way, I mean delimiter tokens. The opening brace can be seen as redundant, but a language could go like this (in fact I'm sure there are languages exactly like this but I don't know them well):

```
if condition:
    statement
    other_statement()
end
```

PS2: 2019, 4 years after this answer. I learned Python and totally got used to its semantic indentation and don't find it difficult to read at all. Especially with the aid of modern IDEs that draw vertical bars to aid in identifying indent blocks.

Comment: I like that syntax because it's a good compromise and avoids braces. But it's costly for one-line statements, where e.g. in C we can leave away the braces completely :(

Comment: instead of nested if...elif you can try using dictionaries, and/or, continue, return, nested functions...

Comment: @aoeu256 totally not the point of the question and my answer either.

Comment: I think in general a powerful IDE makes indentation vs. brackets less important, as the tooling makes the downsides of both less severe. The most interesting case is when you don't have a "powerful IDE, when you're using something more akin to notepad.

Comment: If someone is using notepad to code in 2022 there are more problems to care